# NamedTemporaryFile exists, but external program can't access it

Tags: python, temporary-files, blast

This is a follow-up of sorts to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35228319/how-to-used-namedtemporaryfile-and-when-is-it-closed) about using `NamedTemporaryFile()`

I have a function that creates and writes to a temporary file. I then want to use that file in a different function, which calls a terminal command that uses that file (the program is from the Blast+ suite, `blastn`).

```
def db_cds_to_fna(collection="genes"):  # collection gets data from mongoDB

    tmp_file = NamedTemporaryFile()
    # write stuff to file

    return tmp_file

def blast_all(blast_db, collection="genes"):        

    tmp_results = NamedTemporaryFile()    
    db_fna = db_cds_to_fna(collection) # should return another file object

    Popen(
        ['blastn',
         '-query', db_fna.name,
         '-db', blast_db,
         '-out', tmp_results.name,
         '-outfmt', '5']  # xml output
    )

    return tmp_results
```

When I call `blast_all`, I get an error from the `blastn` command:

```
Command line argument error: Argument "query". File is not accessible:  `/var/folders/mv/w3flyjvn7vnbllysvzrf9y480000gn/T/tmpAJVWoz'
```

But, just prior to the `Popen` call, if I do `os.path.isfile(db_fna.name)` it evaluates to `True`. I can also do

```
print Popen(['head', db_fna.name]).communicate(0)
```

And it properly spits out the first lines of the file. So the file exists, and it's readable. Further, I use the same strategy to call a different program from the same blast+ suite (`makeblastdb`, see question linked at the top) and it works. Is there possibly some problem with permissions? FWIW `blastn` returns the same error if the file doesn't exist, but it seems clear that I'm correctly creating the file and it's readable when I make the `Popen` call, so I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I figured out the things conspiring to cause this behavior. First, the `Popen()` function does not normally wait until the external command finishes before proceeding past it. Second, because as user glibdud mentioned [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35228682/3742902) to my other question, `NamedTemporaryFile` acts like [`TemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) in that

> It will be destroyed as soon as it is closed (including an implicit close when the object is garbage collected).

Since the end of my `blast_all()` function does not return the `query` temp file, it gets closed and garbage collected while the external `blastn` command is running, so the file is deleted. I'm guessing that the external `head` command goes so quickly it doesn't encounter this problem, but `blastn` can take up to a couple of minutes to run.

So the solution is to force `Popen()` to wait:

```
Popen(
    ['blastn',
     '-query', db_fna.name,
     '-db', blast_db,
     '-out', tmp_results.name,
     '-outfmt', '5']  # xml output
).wait()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem may be that the OS has not synced the file to disk. After you write to the file descriptor do:

```py
tmp_file.flush()
os.fsync(tmp_file)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fsync

Answer (score 1):

I've had a very similar problem at some point. I was searching for ages, thinking I was never going to find the cause.

In my case, the issue was due to file-system latency. I think I ended up putting a dirty hack in place using `time.sleep` to give the file system some time to create the temp file before starting to access it in the subproces.

Hope that helps!

Comment: But if this were the problem, why does the `Popen(['head', db_fna.name])` run just fine? The temp file is there and written...

Comment: Ha! Your comment reminded me of something... I put a `.wait()` at the end of the `Popen` call, and it worked. The `blastn` function takes a while to run, I bet the function kept running, and returned the results file, at which point the input file went out of scope and was garbage collected/deleted before `blastn` was done with it.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not exactly sure. Have you tried it though?

Comment: Nice, well I'm happy you didn't need to do a `sleep`!

Comment: Do you want to amend your answer to include the answer so I can mark it? Otherwise, I'll just write an answer to my own question - but since you triggered the idea, I think you should get the credit.

Comment: Oh, no worries, you write it!

Comment: Hey, by the way, I just looked back at my old code and I also did it correctly with `.wait()`, as you suggested.